Selecting Chinese character "温" from MySQL shows question mark "?"
If I select the Chinese character "温" from a MySQL database, I expected the result would be "温", but the result shows a question mark ? instead like following:

I've tried other Chinese characters, it can be displayed successfully, for example: 中文:

Did I do anything wrong? How can I solve this problem?
My MySQL version is: 5.7.44 MySQL Community Server (GPL).

Maybe your shell can't display such characters? Did you check in your application whether you're also facing any problems there?

Did you try surrounding the Chinese character with single quotes instead of double quotes?

Try converting your database to utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci and see if that helps. Also ensure that the tool that is showing chinese characters actually have font able to show chinese characters, otherwise it will show as unknown glyph (? or in browser nothing/empty glyph symbol)

@NicoHaase Yes that's my application's problem! I tried submitting the Chinese character "温" on a HTML form (I use Chrome as my browser), after the character was inserted to the database, I refreshed the web page (it queries the data from the database) and the character could be displayed successfully.

If your app displays the Chinese character successfully as written in your last comment, then what's the problem? Why does it matter if the character does not display well in the terminal?

@Justinas you are mixing character sets and collations up. What matters from the display point of view is the character set (utf8mb4), not the collation (utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci). Collation is used for comparison (ordering, equality). The OP needs to check if the column uses utf8mb4 character set.

@Shadow Got it, thank you. From CREATE TABLE we can see that character set is utf8

@Shadow I used XAMPP to operate the database. Maybe it's because the XAMPP's Terminal app does not support the character I entered.

@NicoHaase may I ask you what should I do with this question after you answered me?

@JohnWang the terminal is a plain microsoft windows command line. I think lots of Chinese people would complain if it did not support all Chinese characters :)

@JohnWang check whether the linked questions helped you resolve the problem. If they did not, share more details in this question, such that others could check why the other questions were not helpful
